# Convergence of $\sum_{k=1}^\infty k\sin\frac1k$

Tags: sequences-and-series

$\sum_{k=1}^\infty k\sin\frac1k$.

Can anyone provide me with a hint? Which test would help me in this situation?

Comment: Do the terms have limit $0$?

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** Note that  $n\sin \frac1n = \dfrac{\sin\frac1n}{\frac1n}$.

Note also that as $n\to\infty$, you have that $\frac1n\to 0$.

You probably know that $\frac{\sin u}{u}\to 1$ as $u\to 0$.

So the terms you are summing approach $1$. What does this tell you?

Comment: Beautiful, thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. Note that @AndreNicolas suggested essentially the same thing in his comment.